# WebStorm TypeScript inspection errors - isn't shown at realtime?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm 2017.2.4 with Angular 4.3 - TypeScript doesn't show errors : 
[image]

**Question**

How can I see real time inspections ? immediately ?

(I've already tried invalidating and clear cache).

configuration :

[image]

**ts.config.json** file :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es6",
            "es2015.iterable"
        ],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "./node_modules/tns-core-modules/*",
                "./node_modules/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "platforms",
        "**/*.aot.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using new HttpClient?

Comment: @yurzui yes I do. https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPgq2.png

Comment: `this.http.post<{Result: any}>(...` or merely `this.http.post<any>`

Comment: Or create interface

Comment: @yurzui Thanks you. but this only to allow the dot notation ( right?). still -  I have the problem where typescript doesn;t recognize errors on the fly.for example - when I write `blabla()` it support to show an error - but it doesn't. - only after I restart the typescript service.

Comment: Or `.do((data: any) =>`

Comment: Check also this https://angular.io/guide/http#typechecking-the-response

Comment: `it support to show an error - but it doesn't. ` That's strange..

Comment: @yurzui do you see it ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcLQX.png

Comment: Yeah, cannot find name 'notexists'. But i'm trying it on 2017.1

Comment: @yurzui Yeah - but the error is shown ONLY AFTER I restart the typescript service .

Comment: Angular 5 supports only `~2.4.0` So i would change typescript version. And maybe this has nothing to do with angular and you should write issue in webstorm support

Comment: @yuruzi - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29282

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WebStorm 2017.2.4** doesn't support TypeScript **2.6** (API was broken). This problem was fixed in **WebStorm 2017.2.5**.

See also: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/10/webstorm-2017-2-5/

Comment: Works great. Thank you.